# Convert RenderTexture to Texture2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, io, export

I need to save a RenderTexture object to a .png file that will then be used as a texture to wrap about a 3D object. My problem is right now I can't save a RenderTexture object using EncodeToPNG() because RenderTexture doesn't include that method. How can I convert a RenderTexture object into a Texture2D object? Thank you!

```
// Saves texture as PNG file.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class SaveTexture : MonoBehaviour {

    public RenderTexture tex;

    // Save Texture as PNG
    void SaveTexturePNG()
    {
        // Encode texture into PNG
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
        Object.Destroy(tex);

        // For testing purposes, also write to a file in the project folder
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../SavedScreen.png", bytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create new `Texture2D`, use `RenderTexture.ReadPixels` to read the pixels from `RenderTexture` into the new `Texture2D`. Finally, Call  `Texture2D.Apply();` to apply the changed pixels.

```
Texture2D toTexture2D(RenderTexture rTex)
{
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512, 512, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // ReadPixels looks at the active RenderTexture.
    RenderTexture.active = rTex;
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rTex.width, rTex.height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    return tex;
}
```

Usage:

```
public RenderTexture tex;
Texture2D myTexture = toTexture2D(tex);
```

---

You can make it an extension method (restore the previous active RenderTexture to avoid surprises):

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static Texture2D toTexture2D(this RenderTexture rTex)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(rTex.width, rTex.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        var old_rt = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = rTex;

        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rTex.width, rTex.height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();

        RenderTexture.active = old_rt;
        return tex;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public RenderTexture tex;
Texture2D myTexture = tex.toTexture2D();
```

Comment: Why do I need to set the rTex to RenderTexture .active?

Comment: @ErayTuncer `Texture2D.ReadPixels` will copy a rectangular pixel area from the currently **active**  `RenderTexture` and store it in `Texture2D/tex`. It's better to read the doc of each property function used in this answer.

Comment: You may need to store the existing `RenderTexture` and restore it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics API has an easier way to do that:

```
Graphics.CopyTexture(sourceRenderTexture, destinationTexture2D);
```

Comment: Note that the texture formats must be identical or it will throw an error. If you do get an error [see here for a list of tex format codes](https://forum.unity.com/threads/run-into-error-graphics-copytexture-d3d11-base-formats-src-9-dst-27.1169033/) so you can understand what to change one of the textures to.