# Unity - Can I make a mirror in 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am making a topdown tilebased 2D game. In this game, I want to make 1 of the walls into a mirror, like you can see on [this](https://youtu.be/xIVy8HL06vE?t=1m48s) video. Now, I know the game in the trailer is made in RPG Maker, but I want to make my game in Unity 3D.

I have tried to set a camera right next to the mirror, add a RenderTexture on the camera and set that texture on the Sprite, but of course it is not possible to convert a RenderTexture to a Sprite, so this did not end up working.

So my question is, is it possible to create a mirror like in the trailer?

Comment: you should ask this question at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *"it is not possible to convert a RenderTexture to a Sprite"* It is possible and you are on the right track. Please post that code and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: @Programmer I currently don't have any code. I figured the mirror should work like a minimap, so I decided to follow this tutorial: www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-CN2DXqJjM&t

Comment: @neuhaus I have, but since that stachexchange is not that popular I got no response and I figured this might require some code so I thought this would be a fine location to ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get that effect. Just parent the second camera to your character and make it move with your character.

It is possible to convert `RenderTexture` to a `Sprite`. First of all, convert the [`RenderTexture` to `Texture2D`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264468/convert-rendertexture-to-texture2d) then convert the `Texture2D` to `Sprite` with the [`Sprite.Create`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) function.

It is better to disable the second or mirror camera then use `mirrorCam.Render()` to manually render it only when you need to. The script below should get you started. Attach it to an empty GameObject then assign the mirror camera and the target `SpriteRenderer` from the Editor and it should mirror the what the camera is seeing to the `SpriteRenderer`. Don't forget to plugin `RenderTexture` to the mirror camera.

```
public class CameraToSpriteMirror: MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer spriteToUpdate;
    public Camera mirrorCam;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(waitForCam());
    }

    WaitForEndOfFrame endOfFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    IEnumerator waitForCam()
    {
        //Will run forever in this while loop
        while (true)
        {
            //Wait for end of frame
            yield return endOfFrame;

            //Get camera render texture
            RenderTexture rendText = RenderTexture.active;
            RenderTexture.active = mirrorCam.targetTexture;

            //Render that camera
            mirrorCam.Render();

            //Convert to Texture2D
            Texture2D text = renderTextureToTexture2D(mirrorCam.targetTexture);

            RenderTexture.active = rendText;

            //Convert to Sprite
            Sprite sprite = texture2DToSprite(text);

            //Apply to SpriteRenderer
            spriteToUpdate.sprite = sprite;

        }
    }

    Texture2D renderTextureToTexture2D(RenderTexture rTex)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(rTex.width, rTex.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rTex.width, rTex.height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();
        return tex;
    }

    Sprite texture2DToSprite(Texture2D text2D)
    {
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(text2D, new Rect(0, 0, text2D.width, text2D.height), Vector2.zero);
        return sprite;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has helped me a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the good old Super Mario 64 way and have the wall be a screen that shows another camera's perspective of another character.

Unity is pretty good at PIP (Picture In Picture) from what I've heard, so may be worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am trying to do

Comment: Sorry about that, should have  read more carefully.
Actually, the way Mario worked wasn't by PIP, the room (and Mario) was just copied and flipped, so essentially you're controlling two characters, only that one is flipped. No PIP needed, just a transparent sprite for a glass effect, and that's that. No extra camera should be needed either

Comment: Additionally, I found this thread: http://adventure-creator.wikia.com/wiki/2D_Mirror/Water_reflections_(Shader_and_script_by_Hedgefield)