# accessing the temporary render buffer used by Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

During the automatic rendering to the screen by the unity Camera, Rendertarget uses an intermediate temporary memory buffer to hold the rendered texture which will be sent to the display.

Can anyone please tell me how can I access that buffer, I want to have all the frames rendered by the camera while playing a game.

But while playing on android platform, the memory will be a big deal to store all frames runtime. How to solve that problem then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RenderTexture.active`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture-active.html) to obtain the current active render texture. You can also [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264468/convert-rendertexture-to-texture2d) that to `Texture2D` if needed.

> But while playing on android platform, the memory will be a big deal
>   to store all frames runtime. How to solve that problem then?

Not sure why you want to access all frames during run-time if this is to convert it to a video then do it on the fly with ffmpeg. Store about 60 frames then pass it to ffmpeg. Repeat again.

If all you want to do is save the frames to local storage then open file stream, retrieve the active render texture about 60 frames then save. Both of these prevents having to store them in the memory while game is running causing out of memory issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Currently, I don't want to make a video. I want to do some analysis of all the frames viewed from the camera. The method you told ReadPixel and GetPixel to have the textures it will slow down the game itself while saving it online. Without slowing down can we somehow get the frames stored in the memory (let's consider memory is the constraint).Just want to clarify the last point of u, u suggested to store the frames in a file stream in android online and just retrieve that when needed?

Comment: Your question asked "how to obtain render buffer". My  answer said `RenderTexture.active`. I don't know why you are talking about ReadPixel and GetPixel. You can use `RenderTexture.active` to retrieve current render buffer. If you are streaming it online, then send the RenderTexture and then release it. Repeat. My point is that no need to store each texture from each frame in the memory as you will run out of memory,

Comment: @Programmer Makes total sense. Where exactly we can call RenderTexture.active? At the end of the frame?