# Converting RenderTexture to Texture2D in Unity 2019

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d, realsense

I'm using **Intel Real Sense** as camera device to capture picture. The capture result is displayed as a `RenderTexture`. Since I need to sent it via `UDP`, I need to convert it to `byte[]`, but it only work for `Texture2D`. Is it possible to convert `RenderTexture` into `Texture2D` in unity 2019?

**Edit:** 
Right now, I'm using this code to convert RenderTexture to Texture2D:

```
Texture2D toTexture2D(RenderTexture rTex)
{
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(rTex.width, rTex.width, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    RenderTexture.active = rTex;
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rTex.width, rTex.height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();

    return tex;
}
```

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264468/convert-rendertexture-to-texture2d), which doesn't work anymore for unity 2019 since if I display the texture it only give me white texture.

**Edit 2:**
Here how i called that function:

```
//sender side
Texture2D WebCam;
public RawImage WebCamSender;
public RenderTexture tex;
Texture2D CurrentTexture;

//receiver side
public RawImage WebCamReceiver;
Texture2D Textur;
IEnumerator InitAndWaitForWebCamTexture()
{

    WebCamSender.texture = tex;
    CurrentTexture = new Texture2D(WebCamSender.texture.width, 
    WebCamSender.texture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false, false);
    WebCam = toTexture2D(tex);

    while (WebCamSender.texture.width < 100) //WebCam
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    StartCoroutine(SendUdpPacketVideo());
}
```

then i'll send it via network like this :

```
IEnumerator SendUdpPacketVideo()
{
        ...
        CurrentTexture.SetPixels(WebCam.GetPixels());
        byte[] PNGBytes = CurrentTexture.EncodeToPNG();
        ...
}
```

On receiver side, i'm gonna decode it and display on raw image:

```
....
Textur.LoadImage(ReceivedVideo);
WebCamReceiver.texture = Textur;
...
```

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: Could you add your code please?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 i plan to create a windows program.

Comment: @derHugo I haven't found a working code yet to convert rendertexture to texture2D. I'll post the nonworking one, wait.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimized way to do this is:

```
public Texture2D toTexture2D(RenderTexture rTex)
{
    Texture2D dest = new Texture2D(rTex.width, rTex.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    dest.Apply(false);
    Graphics.CopyTexture(rTex, dest);
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code works better than before but it still did not display the texture. Only a grey display like this : https://i.imgur.com/2DUDMHy.jpg

Comment: How exactly do you call this method?

Comment: i'm using IEnumerator to generate frame by frame and set it on RawImage as texture.

Comment: I've added it on the post.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 do you not maybe have to `Apply` **after** `Graphics.Copy`? Why doing it before? The docs also says the Data formats have to match .. but afaik by default RenderTexture is 24-bit RGB and has no alpha channel except OP changed that.

Comment: @derHugo I once also try using graphic.copy and apply after that, but found out, it won't work on different texture. Do u know ho to change alpha channel?

Comment: @derHugo  if you don't need to access the pixels on the CPU, you could use Graphics.CopyTexture for fast GPU-side texture data copies. Note that calling Apply may undo the results of previous calls to Graphics.CopyTexture.