# Turning a material into a texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a noise map being auto-generated through a material.  I want to then turn that material into a texture or like a png.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could for example use [`Graphics.Blit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html)

and do something like

```
public Texture2D MaterialToTexture2D(Material material)
{
    // Here you'll have to define the target resolution of the texture
    // either you create the render texture by code or already reference one via the Inspector
    // we also don't need depth information for rendering
    var targetRenderTexture = new RenderTexture(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0);

    // Blit takes a source texture, uses the given material on it
    // so since you only want your material itself we simply pass in a completely white texture as source
    var sourceTexture = new new Texture2D(targetRenderTexture.width, targetRenderTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    var sourcePixels = sourceTexture.GetPixels();
    for(var i = 0; i < sourcePixels.Length; i++)
    {
        sourcePixels[i] = Color.white;
    }
    sourceTexture.SetPixels(sourcePixels);
    sourceTexture.Apply();

    // Now we use Blit to "render" the material onto the given sourceTexture and store the result in the targetRenderTexture
    Graphics.Blit(sourceTexture, targetRenderTexture, yourMaterial);

    // Now that we have the RenderTexture we can convert it back to a Texture2D
    // source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264468/convert-rendertexture-to-texture2d

    // here you can define the target format and whether the texture shall generate mip chain according to your needs
    var finalTexture = new Texture2D(targetRenderTexture.width, targetRenderTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    // store the currently active Rendertexture
    var old_rt = RenderTexture.active;
    // then make our RenderTexture the active one
    RenderTexture.active = rTex;

    // Now we read the pixels of our Render Texture into the final target Texture2D
    finalTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rTex.width, rTex.height), 0, 0);
    finalTexture.Apply();

    // And restore the original state
    RenderTexture.active = old_rt;

    return finalTexture;
}
```

And finally you can now use that `finalTexture` or if your goal was to convert it to an actual image file use e.g.

```
var bytes = finalTexture.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "RenderedMaterial.png", bytes);
```