# Texture stitching performance

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-processing, texture2d

I need to stitch screen captures together into a panoramic texture to be saved as png.
The process is solely meant to run in editor and though it works, it can get really slow.

```
    byte[] MergeTexturesToBytes(List<Texture2D> textures)
    {
        // All textures have same dimensions, so we can define the panoramic texture
        int width = textures[0].width;
        int totWidth = width * textures.Count;
        int height = textures[0].height;

        // Setting the final image
        Texture2D result = new Texture2D(totWidth, height);

        // iterating each texture in order
        for (int t = 0; t < textures.Count; t++)
        {
            Texture2D tex = textures[t];

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    // This is where the current texture is offset onto the final texture so it does not draw on top of previous one
                    int resultX = x + width * t;
                    Color color = tex.GetPixel(x, y);
                    result.SetPixel(resultX, y, color);
                }
            }
        }
        result.Apply();
        // Return the byte array for this final image
        return result.EncodeToPNG();
    }
```

I can have 3 to 5 images to stitch, resolution is defined by the editor screen ratio. Also, this is for a lot of levels, up to 1000, which would stall the editor for hours.

The algorithm is simple, it runs each image and place it onto the final texture with x offset so they aligned but I'm wondering if there would be anything faster than that.

EDIT:

I was able to optimize by half with the following approach:

```
    int width = textures[0].width;
    int totWidth = width * textures.Count;
    int height = textures[0].height;

    // Setting the final image
    Texture2D result = new Texture2D(totWidth, height);

    List<Color[]> colors = new List<Color[]>();
    List<Color> resultColor = new List<Color>();

    for(int i = 0; i < textures.Count; i++) 
    {
        colors.Add(textures[i].GetPixels());
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < textures.Count; t++)
        {
            int offset = width * j;
            resultColor.AddRange(colors[t].Skip(offset).Take(width));
        }
    }
    result.SetPixels(resultColor.ToArray());
    result.Apply();
```

The main change is that it only calls one SetPixels method and focuses more on data block movement.

Answer (score 1):

you're setting each individual pixel by the CPU one by one.

Using the graphics card this should be quite a bit faster.

you can use the [Graphics.Blit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html) method to render a texture into a RenderTexture. Using the overload with "offset" and "scale", so you don't need to pass a Material or something like that.

afterwards you can can convert the RenderTexture to a Texture2D again:
[Convert RenderTexture to Texture2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264468/convert-rendertexture-to-texture2d)

Comment: I had a look but could not figure out how to use that for my problem. Graphics.Blit takes one source to draw on a render texture. If you could extend with an example.